# How to design a message/comment table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am designing a message/comment table in MySQL for social networking site. I have a messaging system where participating two users (only two and not more than that) will have single/unique thread. So, whenever a user is messaging another user then it will check whether both user had unique thread IF NOT then it will create unique thread for both user.

```
create table comment_threads (
thread_id int (PK),
user_id_1 int,
user_id_2 int,
created datetime
);

create table comments (
comment_id int (PK),
thread_id int (FK),
comment text,
created datetime
);
```

Whenever a user messages another user each time then I have to check whether both of the participating user had previous thread so i have to query the database for that (QUERY 1). And then again if there wasn't any thread to create a thread in comment_thread (QUERY 2). Then again to post comment in comment table (QUERY 3). So I have to query two or three times for messaging.

Questions:

1. Is the above tables correct way of solving my problem or it needs some correction?
2. Is there any other better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to have 2 tables.. 1 table should be fine:

```
create table comments (
comment_id int (PK),
parent_id int,
user_id_1 int,
user_id_2 int,
comment text,
created datetime
);
```

For a new thread, set the parent_id to 0. For future comments, you can set the parent_id to the ID of first comment.

This way, you can also do multi-level threaded conversations, and it makes it easy to do stuff like 'comments I've posted'.

As per Itay's answer, you should use some caching mechanisms to improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't know which user left which message
2. When you instantiate the message system with a thread, cache the two users ids and thread id, no need to run to DB for each submit (this is not that simple, but rather a direction for you, you will need some failsafes mechanisems)
3. I would buffer in memory the thread and submit to DB only at a later time (or just use a memory table)
4. since this is a two users only, one thread only system, you can de-normalize and do the entire thread in one record inside a huge text field where you concatenate the latest entry to the end. Again, this is just a direction and not the complete solution.